# Music streaming services does not work in Chromium

Tags: chromium, music, spotify

I have a newbie question. I'm just starting my adventure with Ubuntu, but I encountered a small but annoying problem. While using Chromium Spotify Web Player just does not work. The only thing I receive is error on the top of the web page on pink background saying: "Unfortunately there was an error while playing song, load again" or something like this (I'm not using English version, so I'm not sure how exactly translate this error). Then I even can't click one Pause/Play button becouse nothing happens. Also one of my favourite online radio does not work. It is loading forever and buttons also does not work. Do I have to install any specific plugin to make it work? I would like to mention that in Firefox everything works perfectly fine but I want to stick with Chromium becouse of sync with my second PC. I know there is Spotify app for Linux but working radio is still important for me.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't personally use spotify, but I do know that Chromium does not come with all of the multimedia capabilities packed into it (by default) that Chrome has. If you're not opposed to [installing Chrome](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/desktop/index.html), you might give it a go. Chrome should still happily sync with your second PC.

Comment: I'd love to but unfortunately I'm using 32bit version of Ubuntu and Google discontinued this version of Chrome. Is there any way to install this  multimedia packages manually?

Comment: Have you tried [installing flash](https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/flash-player-chromium.html) (or [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Chromium/Getting-Partner-Flash)). If that doesn't do it for you, it may have something to do with DRM.