# How to make Spotify Web player work in Chromium?

Tags: chromium, spotify

My question is related to a similar [question about Spotify Web Player](https://askubuntu.com/questions/908521/music-streaming-services-does-not-work-in-chromium/1095142#1095142). It appears the Spotify Web Player will not work in Chromium according to this [thread](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2359544). For privacy purposes, I prefer to use Chromium over Chrome. In addition, I use the free version of Spotify, which does not seem to be available for desktop, as noted by Anonymous in the poster's question in this [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7489/how-to-get-the-native-version-of-spotify-running). Lastly, I mostly use Chromium over Firefox due to some functionality problems with add-ons in Firefox. I encountered a screen that looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRcAd.png) when trying to access Spotify Web player.

I tried [installing flash](https://askubuntu.com/questions/341428/how-to-install-flash-player-on-ubuntu/990925#990925) using [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/990925/175814) to fix the problem. I also visited Jorge Castro's discussion of the [differences between Chrome and Chromium](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6253/whats-the-difference-between-google-chrome-and-or-chromium-what-are-the-advant) and found the list of additional plugins to install to make Chromium have similar features to Chrome. Installing these did not work either.

Spotify keeps bringing me to [this page](https://support.spotify.com/us/using_spotify/system_settings/enable-the-spotify-web-player/) and telling me to change the content settings to allow protected content. However, I verified this setting is indeed toggled to the on position, but I continue to see an [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRcAd.png) instead of the web player. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I've always had the free Spotify version for desktop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have installed chromium-browser from universe apt repository, you can make Spotify Web Player work there in Chromium, if you also install Google Chrome. Apparently that brings some shared software that Spotify needs. I tested this in 18.04.

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution is to install curl and apt-transport-https using:

```
sudo apt-get -y install curl apt-transport-https
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.
To solve it download Wine and then download Spotify for Windows on its official site (the Spotify site, not wine).

Comment: Why not use Spotify Snap application, instead of Wine?